# Talmud reference - eagles approaching nests

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, birds

From the News, it states 
"Nachman concluded by recounting a teaching from the Talmud .... The eagle approaches his baby eaglets in the nest very slowly. He makes sure that they notice him gradually, so as not to shock them, because they can die from such fear."

My question: where in the Talmud does it say that? 
Where can one search an english index of the Talmud?

Comment: in terms of a general search, I have this handy http://www.webshas.org/science/sciences/ornithol.htm

Comment: Where is your quote from? "News" is not a very precise source.

Comment: does one need to advertise where the quote comes from? ok. put the quoted parts above in google, and the source is the number one link that comes up: http://www.breakingisraelnews.com/47613/message-from-the-next-world-comes-to-israeli-mystical-rabbi-warns-of-imminent-war-jerusalem/

Comment: @ninamag One should always include a reference when quoting both because A) it's illegal to do otherwise, and B) it can help people see context which could help them find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mentioned by Rashi on [Deuteronomy](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9996#showrashi=true) 32:11 pasuk:

> כנשר הזה, רחמני על בניו ואינו נכנס לקנו פתאום, עד שהוא מקשקש ומטרף על בניו בכנפיו בין אילן לאילן, בין שוכה לחברתה, כדי שיעורו בניו ויהא בהם כח לקבלו
>
> He guided them [Israel] with mercy and compassion like an eagle, which
>   is merciful towards its own fledglings and does not enter its nest
>   suddenly. [Rather,] it beats and flaps its wings above its young
>   between one tree and another, between one branch and another, in order
>   that its young should awaken and have the strength to receive it.

So the source is probably Midrashic, though it doesn't seem to be in the Medrash Rabba or Tanchuma.

Comment: On what pasuk ?

Comment: thank you. great job. what is the bibliographic information of the above hebrew quote by "Rashi on that pasuk"? so, it is not in the Talmud, then? i understand that the rough translation should be, "The eagle approaches his baby eaglets in the nest very slowly. He makes sure that they notice him gradually, so as not to shock them, because they can die from such fear", but could somebody please translate the above hebrew quote in a wooden literal translation into english, so i can try to figure out the hebrew words and its corresponding translation? thanks.

Comment: thank you! Deuteronomy 32:11 As an eagle awakens its nest, hovering over its fledglings, it spreads its wings, taking them and carrying them on its pinions. http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9996#showrashi=true